# ¿Cómo dar nombre a conjuntos de datos en el eje X usando pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy utilizando matplotlyb.pyplot para una representación gráfica. En el eje X tengo representados los días de un año (de 1 a 365). Querría saber como podría modificar las etiquetas del eje para dividirlo en intervalos de meses. Por ejemplo, tomar los valores en X de 1 a 31 y llamar a este intervalo 'Enero'. Gracias!

Este es el código:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    plt.plot(list2,'-.',list1,'-.')
    plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(list1)), 
                       list1, list2, 
                       facecolor='green', 
                       alpha=0.25)
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.axis([1,365,-25,35])
    
    plt.xlabel('Days in a year')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (degrees Celsius)')
    plt.title('Representation of record high and record low temperatures by day of the year')
    # add a legend with legend entries (because we didn't have labels when we plotted the data series)
    plt.legend(['Minimum temperature by the day of the year over the period 2005-2014', 'Maximum temperature by the day of the year over the period 2005-2014'])
    
    plt.show()
```

Y la gráfica resultante:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica el código que has escrito y el resultado obtenido. Con eso podremos trabajar en respuestas concretas.

Comment: Aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555819/months-as-axis-ticks se pregunta lo mismo, e incluso la gráfica es muy similar.